# React pass data from front-end to back-end node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to learn a little bit more of REACT and APIs. I'm using a NASA API and so far I'm able to make a call a return the NASA pic of the day as well an image from a random date.
What I would like to do now is to have an option that let the "user" pick a date. But I'm not really sure how to pass that date from the input to the back-end where the API call are requested

```
class NasaDaily extends Component {
  state = {
    dailyPics: [],
    randomPic: [],
    date: ''
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    const dailyPics = await getDailyPics();
    const randomPic = await getRandomPic();
    this.setState({ dailyPics })
    this.setState({ randomPic })
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <>

        <input
          name="date"
          id="date"
          min="1995-06-16"
          type="date"
          className="active"
          value={this.state.date}
          onChange={event => this.setState({ date: event.target.value })}
        >
        </input>
```

here's the controller

```
const start = new Date(1995, 6, 16)
const end = new Date()
function randomDate(start, end) {
  return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()))
}

async function nasaRandom(req, res) {
  const randDate = randomDate(start, end).toISOString().slice(0, 10)
  axios.get(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY_NASA}&date=${randDate}`)
    .then(response => res.json(response.data))
}
```

nasa-api fetch

```
export function getRandomPic() {
  return fetch('/api/')
    .then(res => res.json())
}
```

route

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const ctrl = require('../controllers/nasa')

router.get('/', ctrl.nasaRandom)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to take the date state from your client and send it to your API endpoint through a POST request. Your API endpoint will then take the date from the req.body and insert that into it's own request to the NASA API. Your API will await the NASA API's response and send that back to the client once it is received.

Client

```
await axios({
  method: "POST",
  url: "yourAPI/customDate",
  data: {
    date: this.state.date 
  },
  withCredentials: false
}).then((response) => {
  //response from your API that includes the NASA API image
})
```

Server

```
router.post("/customDate", async (req, res) => {
  const customDate = req.body.date
  await axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: `https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY_NASA}&date=${customDate}`,
    withCredentials: false
  }).then((response) => {
    res.send(response.image)
  })
})
```

Comment: But how? This is exactly the part that I don't know how. I can get the input and "save" to state. But how do I pass this to my axios call

Comment: @DavidCibin I don't know where you are calling the nasaRandom function that holds your axios call. You can access the state with this.state.date if that's where the confusion is. You also need to pass it as a parameter to the function if you plan on keeping the axios call within nasaRandom.

Comment: Probably that's what I have to do, pass it as a parameter, but this is still new to me and I'm kind lost. BTW I updated my post with more info

Comment: @DavidCibin Stay with me on this. I'm going to make another answer in a second.

Comment: Sorry if I am not being clear. I know how to do that in the front-end. But for best practice I'm learning not to do the API call in the front end as you expose the API key in the front end.

Answer (score 1):

You should have one more axios call from the React to your NodeJS as React(front-end) and NodeJS(back-end) will be two different things.

It is either you call directly from React to NASA API (which will exposed your API Key in the front-end) or React axios call to your NodeJS and then NodeJS axios call (API Key) to NASA API.